# SwiftUI + UIViewRepresentable: how would you have the UIViewRepresentable respond to a binding

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit, uiviewrepresentable

**Context**

I am implementing a video player that should expose `play`, `pause` `mute` and `unmute` functions. In my case it would be ideal if these boolean settings are passed in as bindings. I have a basic `UIViewRepresentable` working here:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit
import UIKit


//MARK:- video player with play/pause API

struct MediaPlayerFeedItem : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    var urls: [String]
    @Binding var shouldPlay: Bool
    @Binding var shouldMute: Bool

    var vc =  AVPlayerViewController()
    @State var pauseAll: Bool = false
    

    //MARK:- API
        
    // @use: play from beginning
    func play(){
        self._goPlay()
    }
        
    // @use: pause video
    func pause(){
        vc.player?.pause()
    }
    
    // @use respond to mute event
    func mute(){
    }
    
    // @use: respond to umute event
    func unmute(){
    }
    
        
    //MARK:- view
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        if shouldPlay {
            _goPlay()
        } else {
            let items = _makeItems()
            if items.count > 0 {
                let player = AVQueuePlayer(items: items)
                vc.player =  player
                vc.showsPlaybackControls = false
                vc.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
                vc.player?.seek(to: .zero)
                vc.player?.pause()
            }
        }
        return vc
    }
    
    // @use: this fn will fire when `shouldPlay` is updated. at which point you can
    //       `play` or `pause` the video as desired
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
    }
    
    //MARK:- playback

    private func _goPlay(){

        let items = _makeItems()
        guard items.count > 0 else { return }
        
        let player = AVQueuePlayer(items: items)
        vc.player =  player
        vc.showsPlaybackControls = false
        vc.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        vc.player?.seek(to: .zero)
        vc.player?.play()
       
        NotificationCenter.default
            .addObserver(
                forName: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                object: items[items.count-1],
                queue: .main
            ){_ in
                self._goPlay()
            }

    }
    
    // @use: make a new set of avplayeritems before each
    // invocation of _goPlay loop
    private func _makeItems() -> [AVPlayerItem] {
        return urls
            .map{ URL(string: $0) }
            .filter{ $0 != nil }
            .map{ AVPlayerItem(url: $0!) }
    }
    
    

}
```

Use:

```
  MediaPlayerFeedItem(urls: [url1,url2], shouldPlay: $shouldPlay, shouldMute: .constant(true) )
```

The issue is that I am not sure how to connect the `UIViewRepresentable` with its binding values. That is, when `shouldPlay` change to true, it would be nice if `MediaPlayerFeedItem` just calls `play()` by itself.

===================================================

**Update**

I forgot to mention that in an earlier implementation, I had this:

```
func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
    if shouldPlay {
        play()
    } else {
        pause()
    }
}
```

This is where the behavior of `MediaPlayerFeedItem` is truly baffling. Both `updateViewController` and its respective functions calls for `play` or `pause` fires as expected, but it doesn't seem to do anything in terms of playing or pausing the video.

For example, if init `MediaPlayerFeedItem` with `shouldPlay` set to a true value binding, then the video plays regardless of the pause command that happens later. If I init `MediaPlayerFeedItem` to `shouldPlay` set to false binding, and then set it it true again, the video does not play at all. The video loads, it just remains paused at the first frame.

I am inclined to say that the issue is in the `_goPlay` function itself, but the video does play and loop if I just run `_goPlay` in the `makeUIViewController` function regardless of whether `shouldPlay` is set to true.

Per @aheze suggestion, I added print statements in `play`, `pause` and `_goPlay` functions, the behavior is as follows: @aheze when I init `MediaFeedItem` with false binding, I am getting 3 `pausing` prints on initialization. And then 10 seconds later when i set `shouldPlay` to true, I get one `play` print statement, and no subsequent `pause` statement. The funnhy thing is that I am getting `loop play` print statement as well from `_goPlay` function in the `NotificationCenter` call, so it means the video is playing .. it's just not rendering. Note I am initializing all new `AVPlayerItem` list on each loop, this is needed because i cannot share them across different playing loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
struct VideoPlayerView: UIViewRepresentable {

    var urls: [URL]
    var playOnLoad: Bool
    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState

    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return PlayerUIViewQueue(urls: urls, playOnLoad: playOnLoad, frame: .zero)
    }
    
    // @use: on `appState` context change, `play` `pause` or `resume` the video
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<VideoPlayerView>) {

        if let uiv = uiView as? PlayerUIViewQueue {
            
            switch appState.getTokenPlayCommand() {
            case .pause:
                uiv.pause()
            case .play:
                uiv.playFromBeginning()
            case .resume:
                uiv.resume()
            }
        }
    }

}


class PlayerUIViewQueue: UIView {
    
    private var URLs: [URL]

    // player references
    private let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
    private var current_mutli : AVQueuePlayer? = nil
    private var current_single: AVPlayer? = nil
    
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        playerLayer.frame = bounds
    }


    init(urls: [URL], playOnLoad:Bool, frame: CGRect){
        
        self.URLs = urls

        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        if self.URLs.count == 1 {
            print("if case")
            initSinglePlayer()
        } else {
            print("else case")
            loopAll()
        }
    }
    

    //MARK:- API
    
    func resume(){
        print("RESUMNING")
        current_mutli?.play()
        current_single?.play()
    }
    
    func pause(){
        print("PAUSING")
        current_mutli?.pause()
        current_single?.pause()
    }
    
    func playFromBeginning(){
        print("playFromBeginning")
        current_mutli?.seek(to: .zero)
        current_mutli?.play()
        current_single?.seek(to: .zero)
        current_single?.play()
    }
    
    
    //MARK:- player utils
    
    private func initSinglePlayer(){
        
        if URLs.count == 0 { return }

        let player = AVPlayer(url: URLs[0])
        player.actionAtItemEnd = .none
        self.current_single = player

        playerLayer.player = player
        playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill

        layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

        player.play()
        NotificationCenter.default
            .addObserver(
                self,
                selector: #selector(loopPlayerSingle(notification:)),
                name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                object: player.currentItem
            )
        
    }
    
    
    @objc func loopPlayerSingle(notification: Notification) {
        if let playerItem = notification.object as? AVPlayerItem {
            playerItem.seek(to: .zero, completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }

    
    // @use: on each `loopAll()` invocation, reinit
    // the player with all video `items`
    private func loopAll(){

        let items  = URLs.map{ AVPlayerItem.init(url: $0) }
        let player = AVQueuePlayer(items: items)
        self.playerLayer.player = player
        self.current_mutli = player

        player.seek(to: .zero)
        player.play()
        
        playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        
        NotificationCenter.default
            .addObserver(
                self,
                selector: #selector(loopPlayerMulti(notification:)),
                name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                object: player.items().last
            )
        
    }
    

    
    @objc private func loopPlayerMulti(notification: Notification) {
        loopAll()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to check out the comments:

```
// @use: this fn will fire when `shouldPlay` is updated. at which point you can
//       `play` or `pause` the video as desired
func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
```

As the comments say, whenever `shouldPlay` is updated, `updateUIViewController` will be called. So, you could do something like this:

```
func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
    if shouldPlay {
        play()
    } else {
        pause()
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh yeah so I added those comments actually, for some reason when I did what you wrote ... it actually conflicted with the play() called in `makeUIViewController` ..

Comment: @xiaolingxiao ah, I see... what do you mean by "conflicted" though?

Comment: Sorry I meant it doesn't actually do anything. Both `pause` and `play` runs when the context changes. However, if  init MediaPlayerFeedItem with `shouldPlay` set to `$trueValue`, then the video plays regardless of the pause command that happens later. If I init `MediaPlayerFeedItem` to `shouldPlay` set to false, and then set it it true again, the video does not play at all.  The video loads, it just remains paused at the first frame.

Comment: @xiaolingxiao maybe add some `print`s inside `updateUIViewController`, `play`, and `pause` and see if they are getting called more often than expected?

Comment: when I init `MediaFeedItem` with false binding, I am getting 3 `pausing` prints on initialization. And then 10 seconds later when i set `shouldPlay` to true, I get one `play` print statement, and no subsequent `pause` statement. The funnhy thing is that I am getting `loop play` print statement as well from `_goPlay` function in the `NotificationCenter` call, so it means the video is playing .. it's just not rendering. Note I am initializing all new `AVPlayerItem` list on each loop, this is needed because i cannot share them across different playing loops.